# XPath Query Finds Elements Not Inside Selector

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

My XPath query is finding elements that aren't even inside it. For example (from my code below) `business_div` contains the HTML:

```
<div class="foo">
    <div>
       <table>
          ...
          <a class="bar" href="A">link</a>
       </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I run the XPath query `business_div.xpath("//a[@class='bar']/@href").extract()` it returns:

```
["A", "B", "D"] # should just be ["A"]
```

How can I query `business_div` for just `"A"`?

```
<div class="foo">
    <div>
       <table>
          ...
          <a class="bar" href="A">link</a>
       </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="foo">
    <div>
       <table>
          ...
          <a class="bar" href="B">link</a>
       </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="foo">
    <div>
       <table>
          ...
          <!-- Some divs will not contain a link. So I cant do a simple query "//div[contains(@class, "foo")]//a[contains(@class, "bar")]/@href" -->
       </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="foo">
    <div>
       <table>
          ...
          <a class="bar" href="D">link</a>
       </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

My code:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "MySpider"
    ...

    def parse(self, response):
        businesses = []
        business_divs = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'foo')]")

        for business_div in business_divs:
            business = MyItem()
            business["link"] = business_div.xpath("//a[@class='bar']/@href").extract()

            # business["link"] is ["A", "B", "D"]
            # I am expecting business["link"] to simply be ["A"] 
            # in the first loop then ["B"] and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a slight change in xpath will do the trick,

```
business["link"] = business_div.xpath(".//a[@class='bar']/@href").extract()
```